# Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 with padding added

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

This is my model-

```
class CNNHyperModel(HyperModel):
    def __init__(self, input_shape, num_classes):
        self.input_shape = input_shape
        self.num_classes = num_classes

    def build(self, hp):
        model = keras.Sequential()

  


        model.add(
            Conv1D(
                
                filters=hp.Int(
                    "neurons_1", min_value=20, max_value=400, step=20, default=200,),

                
                kernel_size=hp.Int("kernal_sizes_1", min_value=1, max_value=10, step=1, default=3,),
                strides=hp.Int("stride_sizes_1", min_value=1, max_value=10, step=1, default=3,),
                activation="relu",
                input_shape=(25,1),
                padding="same",
            )
        )

        model.add(
            Dropout(
                rate=hp.Float(
                    "dropout_1", min_value=0.0, max_value=0.5, default=0.25, step=0.05,
                )
            )
        )

        model.add(BatchNormalization())


        model.add(
            Conv1D(
                
                filters=hp.Int(
                    "neurons_2", min_value=20, max_value=400, step=20, default=200,),

                
                kernel_size=hp.Int("kernal_sizes_2", min_value=1, max_value=10, step=1, default=3,),
                strides=hp.Int("stride_sizes_2", min_value=1, max_value=10, step=1, default=3,),
                activation="relu",
                padding="same",
            )
        )

        model.add(
            Dropout(
                rate=hp.Float(
                    "dropout_2", min_value=0.0, max_value=0.5, default=0.25, step=0.05,
                )
            )
        )

        model.add(BatchNormalization())

        model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))

        model.add(
            Dropout(
                rate=hp.Float(
                    "dropout_3", min_value=0.0, max_value=0.5, default=0.25, step=0.05,
                )
            )
        )

        model.add(Flatten())

        model.add(
            Dense(
                units=hp.Int(
                    "dense_units_1", min_value=20, max_value=400, step=20, default=100
                ),
                activation=hp.Choice(
                    "dense_activation",
                    values=["relu"],
                    default="relu",
                ),
            )
        )

        model.add(
            Dropout(
                rate=hp.Float(
                    "dropout_4", min_value=0.0, max_value=0.5, default=0.25, step=0.05,
                )
            )
        )

        model.add(
            Dense(
                units=hp.Int(
                    "dense_units_2", min_value=20, max_value=400, step=20, default=100
                ),
                activation=hp.Choice(
                    "dense_activation",
                    values=["relu"],
                    default="relu",
                ),
            )
        )

        model.add(
            Dropout(
                rate=hp.Float(
                    "dropout_4", min_value=0.0, max_value=0.5, default=0.25, step=0.05,
                )
            )
        )

        model.add(
            Dense(
                units=hp.Int(
                    "dense_units_3", min_value=20, max_value=400, step=20, default=100
                ),
                activation=hp.Choice(
                    "dense_activation",
                    values=["relu"],
                    default="relu",
                ),
            )
        )

        model.add(
            Dropout(
                rate=hp.Float(
                    "dropout_4", min_value=0.0, max_value=0.5, default=0.25, step=0.05,
                )
            )
        )

        model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))



        model.compile(
            optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(
                hp.Float(
                    "learning_rate",
                    min_value=1e-6,
                    max_value=1e-2,
                    sampling="LOG",
                    default=1e-3,
                )
            ),
            loss="binary_crossentropy",
            metrics=[f1_m],
        )
        return model
```

The error I'm getting-

```
ValueError: in user code:    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:855 train_function  *        return step_function(self, iterator)    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:845 step_function  **        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1285 run        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2833 call_for_each_replica        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3608 _call_for_each_replica        return fn(*args, **kwargs)    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:838 run_step  **        outputs = model.train_step(data)    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 train_step        y_pred = self(x, training=True)    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1030 __call__        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py:394 call        outputs = layer(inputs, **kwargs)    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1030 __call__        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py:1447 call        return getattr(self._module, self._method_name)(*args, **kwargs)    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1006 __call__        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/pooling.py:73 call        data_format=self.data_format)    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper        return target(*args, **kwargs)    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py:5706 pool2d        x, pool_size, strides, padding=padding, data_format=tf_data_format)    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper        return target(*args, **kwargs)    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py:4660 max_pool        name=name)    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py:5344 max_pool        data_format=data_format, name=name)    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:750 _apply_op_helper        attrs=attr_protos, op_def=op_def)    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:601 _create_op_internal        compute_device)    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:3565 _create_op_internal        op_def=op_def)    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:2042 __init__        control_input_ops, op_def)    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1883 _create_c_op        raise ValueError(str(e)) 




 ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node sequential/module_wrapper_4/max_pooling1d/MaxPool}} = MaxPool[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", explicit_paddings=[], ksize=[1, 2, 1, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 1, 1]](sequential/module_wrapper_4/max_pooling1d/ExpandDims)' with input shapes: [?,1,1,360]
```

This happened in the second epoch of my tuning-

[image]

Tuner code-

```
SEED = 1

NUM_CLASSES = 1
INPUT_SHAPE = (25,1)

N_EPOCH_SEARCH = 40
HYPERBAND_MAX_EPOCHS = 40
MAX_TRIALS = 20
EXECUTION_PER_TRIAL = 2
BAYESIAN_NUM_INITIAL_POINTS = 1


def run_hyperparameter_tuning():
    

    hypermodel = CNNHyperModel(input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE, num_classes=NUM_CLASSES)

    output_dir = Path("drive/MyDrive/New_Tuning_upload_latest_3/")
    tuners = define_tuners(
        hypermodel, directory=output_dir, project_name="simple_cnn_tuning_part3"
    )

    results = []
    for tuner in tuners:

        elapsed_time, loss, accuracy = tuner_evaluation(
            tuner, X_test, X_train, y_test, y_train
        )
        logger.info(
            f"Elapsed time = {elapsed_time:10.4f} s, accuracy = {accuracy}, loss = {loss}"
        )
        results.append([elapsed_time, loss, accuracy])
    logger.info(results)


def tuner_evaluation(tuner, X_test, X_train, y_test, y_train):
    set_gpu_config()

    # Overview of the task
    tuner.search_space_summary()

    # Performs the hyperparameter tuning
    logger.info("Start hyperparameter tuning")
    search_start = time.time()
    tuner.search(X_train, y_train, epochs=N_EPOCH_SEARCH, validation_split=0.1)
    search_end = time.time()
    elapsed_time = search_end - search_start

    # Show a summary of the search
    tuner.results_summary()

    # Retrieve the best model.
    best_model = tuner.get_best_models(num_models=1)[0]

    # Evaluate the best model.
    loss, accuracy = best_model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
    return elapsed_time, loss, accuracy


def define_tuners(hypermodel, directory, project_name):
    random_tuner = RandomSearch(
        hypermodel,
        objective= Objective("f1_m", direction='max'),
        seed=SEED,
        max_trials=MAX_TRIALS,
        executions_per_trial=EXECUTION_PER_TRIAL,
        directory=f"{directory}_random_search",
        project_name=project_name,
    )
    hyperband_tuner = Hyperband(
        hypermodel,
        max_epochs=HYPERBAND_MAX_EPOCHS,
        objective= Objective("f1_m", direction='max'),
        seed=SEED,
        executions_per_trial=EXECUTION_PER_TRIAL,
        directory=f"{directory}_hyperband",
        project_name=project_name,
    )
    
    return [random_tuner, hyperband_tuner]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_hyperparameter_tuning()
```

Comment: When you define a CNN model, be aware of the input size changes because it shrinks due to maxpooling layers. Somewhere in your model, input size becomes 1,1, and then you try to shrink it more. Check the journey of your input to your model layers.

Comment: @Kaveh i added padding to my layers..shouldnt that take care of this?

Comment: You have added padding in conv layers, but ``MaxPoolingLayer(2,2)`` makes your input half of size.

Comment: @Kaveh please suggest what to do..I'm a beginner